# How to activate settings in the web app when deployed as deployment-container-image-name

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a "Container Image" on to Web App Service with the following command.

```
az webapp create --name Dev-App --plan Dev-AppServicePlan \
  --resource-group Dev \
  --deployment-container-image-name ...devcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/app-node:latest
```

After the app was successfully deploment I need to change some Environment variables via the following commands.

```
az webapp config appsettings set --name Dev-App --resource-group Dev \
  --settings MONGO_DSN='mongodb://cosmosdb...'

az webapp config appsettings set --name Dev-App --resource-group Dev \
  --settings REDIS_URI='...dev.redis.cache.windows.net:6380...'

az webapp log config --name Dev-App --resource-group Dev \
  --docker-container-logging filesystem
```

Now I have updated and restarted the Web App but it looks like the Image is not redeployed or at least the Environment variables are not there.

```
az webapp update --name Dev-App --resource-group Dev
az webapp restart --name Dev-App --resource-group Dev
```

I looked with log tail to the logs but the logs are also not changed. What I mean with "not changed" is that the log output is stucked to the Timestamp "2021-01-13T13:21:31.100Z" even when I restart the Web App.

```
az webapp log tail --name Dev-App --resource-group Dev
```

In this Articles from MS is described that a restart should be enough but then should also the log output should be changed.

[2: Redeploy a container to Azure App Service after making changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-containers-03)
[Configure a custom container for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container)

Any hint how to activate the new settings in the custom image setup or trigger a redeployment?

FYI: I have also created a question in the azure community.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/230584/how-to-activate-settings-in-the-web-app-when-deplo.html

Comment: did you rebuild the image?

Comment: No. It was not necessary because I only change the ENV-Vars. But to be on the save site I have pushed a new "latest" to the acr and have activated the "Continuous Deployment" but still not new logs.

Comment: unfortunately, you will not see your environment variables in the logs. You can just confirm with echo the variables in the tool just like Kudu, and you can see them in the environment.

Comment: That's clear. What I mean is that the log output is stucked to the first deployment output. There is no new output on stdout even when I restart the App service. I will update the original question. Thanks to show me that my question is not as clear is it should be

Comment: This happened to me earlier, what i did was i renamed the image and then redeployed, also you need to use the webhook for the container https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/deploy-run-container-app-service/

Comment: Just to confirm (if it's not already done) - Docker containers in Web App for Containers are specified using an image:tag combination. For CD you'll need to ensure that any updates to your Docker image don't change the tag. Once you change the tag on an image, it's considered a different image from the initially configured image, and that will cause CI to not pick up the changes.

Eg- initially tag the image with a 'v1 tag and enable CI, later when you update the image and tag the new image with 'v2' , CI will not work.

Comment: @AjayKumar-MSFT I know. I have today pushed another image with another sha256 but the same tag and also restarted the app, nothing changed. The timestamp in the logs is still "2021-01-13T13:21:31.136Z"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution for my problem was that I change the registry from "Private Registry" to "Azure Container Registry" in the "**container settings**" page after running the following command

```
az webapp create --name Dev-App \
--plan Dev-AppServicePlan \
--resource-group chat-Dev \
--deployment-container-image-name devcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/chat-node:latest
```

I have put the acr data into the fields and activated the "Continous Deployment"
[image: ACR Image Source]

After this change every settings change triggers a restart and the ENV Variables was in the new instance.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution that worked for you. To benefit the community members I will also update your answer on your Q&A thread (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/230584/how-to-activate-settings-in-the-web-app-when-deplo.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to updates the environment variables just like add them in the command:

```
docker run --name container_name image -e env_var1 -e env_var2
```

The Azure CLI command just sets the environment variables for the Web App service, you can see them in the Kudu, but it's not the same result as the `docker run` command.

I recommend you use the docker-compose to deploy your image to the Web App service. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app) is the example for the docker-compose. You can update the environment variables in the `environment` option of the docker-compose file in the portal. Then it will restart again and refresh the logs. And the variables you added will also take effect.

Comment: thanks charles. But in his doc is described the when the image is changed will the app-service get the new image https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container. I think the App-Service should work as documented. I don't like to use docker compose just for one image/container.

Comment: @Aleksandar when the image is changed, the SHA checksum will be different and this should prompt App Service to pull the updated image automatically. However, your original question, as long as you've defined your app settings as `ENV setting=value` in your docker file, it should get injected by App Service.

Comment: @Aleksandar The doc just describes how to deploy a custom image to the web app. You change the image, then the web app refreshes the logs, but your question said you just add the environment variables in the app settings, it's not the image.

Comment: I have today pushed another image with another sha256 with the same tag and also restarted the app, nothing changed. The timestamp in the logs is still "2021-01-13T13:21:31.136Z"

Comment: @Aleksandar That's the image problem, not the settings. I don't think there is any relationship between the question and the solution you added.